# time complexity calculation for two for loops with connecting variables

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, time-complexity

what would be the time coplexity of this:

```
for(k=1;K<=n;k*=2)
   for(j=1;j<=k;j++)
     sum++
```

For this i thought as 
1. Outer Loop will run logn times
2. Inner Loop will also run logn times.
because i think inner loop j is related to k. So how much ever k runs, same is the running time for j too.
 So total = O(logn * logn)

but in text they have given total= O(2n-1).
can you please explain

Comment: Random note - I'd be cautious of any material that lists running time as `O(2n-1)` without immediately following it be `= O(n)`.

Answer (score 3):

when k is 1 (sum++) runs 1 times

when k is 2 (sum++) runs 2 times

when k is 4 (sum++) runs 4 times

when k is n = 2^k (sum++) runs 2^k times

so we must calculate

1+2+4+ ... + 2^k = 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + .... + 2^k = (1 - 2^(k+1))/(1-2)

because we put n = 2^k so :

k = log(n)

2^(log(n)) = n^(log(2))

2* 2^k -1 = 2*n - 1

Answer (score 0):

This problem is most easily interpreted by forgetting that the outer loop is there and first looking at the inner loop complexity. Suppose that the inner loop runs 'M' times... then the total number of 'sum++' operations will be,

1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^(M-1)

This sum can be reduced to '2^(M) - 1' by noticing that this is a binary number composed of all 1's. Now the question is what is M? You've already figure this out, M = log(n)+1 (the +1 is because the loop must run at least once). Plugging this into the inner loop complexity leaves us with,

2^(log(n)+1)-1 = 2*n - 1.

Thus the entire loop scales as O(2n-1). Hope this helps!

Comment: By your statement M=Log(n)+1.
are you refering to the outer loop ?

Comment: Yes, the outer loop will run Log(n)+1 times.